# Rails friendly_id gem mass assignment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

I am using "friendly_id 4.0.0" gem for making url user friendly.

below is my user model

```
user.rb model

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name , :use => [:slugged,:history]
  attr_accessible :email, :lname, :name  
end
```

below is my user_controller.rb file

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

But I am getting Can't mass-assign protected attributes: slug exception.
I also try adding slug to attr_accessible as `attr_accessible :email, :lname, :name, :slug`
But still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
attr_accessible :email, :lname, :name
```

[`attr_accessible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001807) protect from mass-assignment

If you try something like following it will work

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.email = params[:user][:email]
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
```